# When I turn on my Laptop or restart this shows up

Tags: boot

I just installed ubuntu os , and when ever I switch on my Laptop or restart my laptop this shows up is this normal?!

[image]

Comment: Normal? ... Yes ... Just checking the root filesystem for errors due to various mostly normal reasons.

Comment: Thanks for the replys got cleared